# Scheduling probes in funf 0.4

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in funf framework, want to develop an app to capture details about running app and screen status but my problem was I want to run this service only between specific time ie 6AM- 12PM

In funf 0.5 there is an option for this by using `LocalTimeOfDayFilter`, but it is not working.

Comment: Hi, having the same problem.  Did you figure out?

Comment: I'm working on it, but yet I didn't find it a complete solution going through some bugs. Will let you know once I find it.